# A couple of cryptic clues for your enjoyment (or otherwise)

Tags: cryptic-clues

```
Missing real time, Walter runs the servers (4, 6).
O' Eternal (2,3).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing real time, Walter runs the servers (4, 6).

> HEAD WAITER - Walter minus letters realt is W which is the head of **w**aiter

O' Eternal (2,3).

> NO END - O is the end of n**o**