# Cryptic crossword clue for your enjoyment

Tags: cryptic-clues

Try this one on for size:

```
 Best "N" (3-5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is probably

> TOP-NOTCH: the definition is "best", and the other part is "reverse wordplay": the "top" of NOTCH is the letter N.

Comment: Is reverse-wordplay a thing?

Comment: @Sid It's not a "standard" type of cryptic clue, but it has been done occasionally. It *could* be considered another definition.

Comment: @Sid, I've actually encountered these regularly in the crossword books I buy. I actually consider these sort at a higher level than regular clues since they both allow for shorter clues *and* distort the mind even more - you have to start at the end and work back - see https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55999/a-couple-of-cryptic-clues-for-your-enjoyment-or-otherwise for example.

Comment: FWIW, the original was going to be `best uppercut` but I though the `"N"` was more cryptic.